# "Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread" AgiServerThread + spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using spring to create a web application and i would  like to integrate asterisk java in my application  .So i followed this [link](https://blogs.reucon.com/asterisk-java/tag/spring/)

But the problem is that when this thread call dao we got the hibernate exception above .
The web application work well (the servlet part ) , but the problem is when this thread call dao we got the exception

And this  is the definition of my session factory

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
    lazy-init="false">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="fabDevDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.abgc.fab.entities</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <!--<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop> -->
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">
                org.hibernate.transaction.BTMTransactionManagerLookup
            </prop>
            <prop key="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: In order to make it easier to analyze the problem, you should post the java code and the stacktrace, too

Comment: Are you using Spring Transaction? If yes, please provide the configuration and proper code to analyze. Also, please post the stacktrace to have a better understanding of your situation.